# Pandas dataframe replace contents based on ID from another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is what my main dataframe looks like:

```
Group    IDs           New ID 
1        [N23,N1,N12]  N102
2        [N134,N100]   N501
```

I have another dataframe that has all the required ID info in an unordered manner:

```
ID    Name    Age
N1    Milo    5
N23   Mark    21
N11  Jacob    22
```

I would like to modify the original dataframe such that all IDs are replaced with their respective names obtained from the other file. So that the dataframe has only names and no IDs and looks like this:

```
Group    IDs               New ID 
1        [Mark,Silo,Bond]  Niki
2        [Troy,Fangio]     Kvyat
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did an answer solve your problem? If yes, please consider [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/694919) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can `.explode` your lists, replace values with `.map` and regroup them with `.groupby`

```
df['ID'] = (df.ID.explode()
   .map(df1.set_index('ID')['Name'])
   .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
)
```

If **New ID** column is not a list, you can use only `.map()`

```
df['New ID'] = df['New ID'].map(df1.set_index('ID')['Name'])
```

Comment: notice: `pandas.explode()` is a function from version 0.25 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

you can try making a dict from your second DF and then replacing on the first using regex patterns (no need to fully understand it, check the comments bellow):

ps: since you didn't provide the full df with the codes, I created with some of them, that's why the print() won't replace all the results.

```
import pandas as pd
# creating dummy dfs
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Group":[1,2], "IDs":["[N23,N1,N12]", "[N134,N100]"], "New ID":["N102", "N501"] })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID":['N1', "N23", "N11", "N100"], "Name":["Milo", "Mark", "Jacob", "Silo"], "Age":[5,21,22, 44]})

# Create the unique dict we're using regex patterns to make exact match
dict_replace = df2.set_index("ID")['Name'].to_dict()
# 'f' before string means fstrings and 'r' means to interpret it as regex
# the \b is a regex pattern that it sinalizes the begining and end of the match
## so that if you're searching for N1, it won't match if it is N11
dict_replace = {fr"\b{k}\b":v for k, v in dict_replace.items()}

# Replacing on original where you want it
df1['IDs'].replace(dict_replace, regex=True, inplace=True)
print(df1['IDs'].tolist())
# >>> ['[Mark,Milo,N12]', '[N134,Silo]']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note the change in my dataframes. In your sample data, the IDs in df that do not exists in df1 IDs. I altered my df to ensure only IDs in df1 were represented. I use the following df

```
print(df)

      Group       IDs   New
0      1  [N23,N1,N11]  N102
1      2     [N11,N23]  N501
```

print(df1)

```
 ID   Name  Age
0   N1   Milo    5
1  N23   Mark   21
2  N11  Jacob   22
```

**Solution**

dict df1.Id and df.Name and map to an exploded df.IDs. Add the result to list.

```
df['IDs'] = df['IDs'].str.strip('[]')#Strip corner brackets
df['IDs'] = df['IDs'].str.split(',')#Reconstruct list, this was done because for some reason I couldnt explode list
#df.explode list and map df1 to df and add to list
df.explode('IDs').groupby('Group')['IDs'].apply(lambda x:(x.map(dict(zip(df1.ID,df1.Name)))).tolist()).reset_index()

  Group                  IDs
0      1  [Mark, Milo, Jacob]
1      2        [Jacob, Mark]
```

Comment: Was this helpful @Shahnawaz? Or you need something else done?